# Como relacionar uma coluna a um dicionario no R?

Tags: r, dicionário

`library(tidyverse)`

Tenho um dataset que possui em uma coluna títulos de artigos e em outra coluna, seus respectivos autores. Reproduzo aqui uma linha deste dataset:

```
df<-tibble(
  titulo= "A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL",
  autores= "CLAUDIO; DIANA; MILENA")

df

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  titulo                   autores               
  <chr>                    <chr>                 
1 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL CLAUDIO; DIANA; MILENA
```

Em seguida, dividi a linha acima segundo os autores usando `separate_rows()`

```
df2<-df %>% 
  separate_rows(autores, sep = "; ")

df2

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  titulo                   autores
  <chr>                    <chr>  
1 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL CLAUDIO
2 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL DIANA  
3 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL MILENA
```

Agora queria que cada autor fosse identificado segundo a sua situação ("docente", "discente" ou "egresso"). Tenho uma planilha com tudo detalhado. Reproduzo aqui um trecho:

```
corpo_programa <- tibble(nome = c("FULANO", "BELTRANO", "CLAUDIO", "MILENA", "DIANA"),
                    situacao = c("docente", "docente", "docente", "discente", "egresso"))

corpo_programa

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  nome     situacao
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 FULANO   docente 
2 BELTRANO docente 
3 CLAUDIO  docente 
4 MILENA   discente
5 DIANA    egresso
```

O que eu queria era utilizar essa planilha como uma espécie de dicionário que comparasse com a coluna "autores" para me gerar uma coluna com a situação de cada autor.

Imaginei que usando a função `setNames()`, eu conseguiria.

```
dicionario<- setNames(corpo_programa$nome, corpo_programa$situacao)
```

Em seguida usei `mutate()`:

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(condicao = dicionario[autores])

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  titulo                   autores condicao
  <chr>                    <chr>   <chr>   
1 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL CLAUDIO NA      
2 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL DIANA   NA      
3 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL MILENA  NA
```

A coluna "condicao", recém-criada, aparece com "NA", quando eu esperava que ela fosse ser preenchida com "docente", "egresso" e "discente".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que você inverteu os argumentos dos `valores` e `nomes` quando criou o objeto `dicionario`. O certo seria assim:

```
dicionario <- setNames(corpo_programa$situacao, corpo_programa$nome)
```

Answer (score 6):

Depois do trabalho que já teve, a maneira mais fácil deve ser com `merge`, não esquecendo que as colunas a fazer corresponder têm nomes diferentes.

```
merge(df2, corpo_programa, by.x = "autores", by.y = "nome")
#  autores                   titulo situacao
#1 CLAUDIO A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL  docente
#2   DIANA A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL  egresso
#3  MILENA A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL discente
```

Outra solução é fazer tudo, a separação da coluna de autores e o *join*, num só pipe:

```
df %>%
  separate_rows(autores, sep = "; ") %>%
  inner_join(corpo_programa, by = c("autores" = "nome"))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  titulo                   autores situacao
#  <chr>                    <chr>   <chr>   
#1 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL CLAUDIO docente 
#2 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL DIANA   egresso 
#3 A URBANIZAÇÃO NEOLIBERAL MILENA  discente
```